# PHP XML Foreach Error

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm getting an error while looping over an element children:

```
 $placeById=simplexml_load_file("http://www.43places.com/service/get_place_by_id?api_key=1234&id=".$placeId);
 $children=$placeById->children;
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach ($children as $child)
 {
      echo '<li>'.$child->child.'</li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';
```

My Output is only this:

- Alabama

Although there are several children, see the XML [here](http://www.43places.com/service/get_place_by_id?api_key=1234&id=103061)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only referencing the first child, try this:

```
$placeById=simplexml_load_file("http://www.43places.com/service/get_place_by_id?api_key=1234&id=".$placeId);
$children=$placeById->children;
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($children->child as $child) {
  echo '<li>'.$child.' - '. $child['id'].'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: thanks its working, I wanted to know one more thing, now that i'm getting each child, and each child have attribute id, but when i'm doing $child['id'], I'm not getting the attribute

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks, there was a problem with double quotes in my codes